# MVCController Data do not persist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Visual Studio 2019. I am having some problems with a controller method.

I have a simple method `Index` in my controller. During page load, `Index` gets executed which is working fine. All the dealer's data is fetched successfully.

This code is working just fine:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page=1)
{
    int PageSize = 30;
    int skip = PageSize * (page.GetValueOrDefault() - 1);
    var Data = GetDealersData(PageSize, skip);
    Data.PageSize = PageSize;

    TempData["currentPageIndex"] = page.GetValueOrDefault();
    TempData["PageSize"] = PageSize;
    TempData["Total"] = Data.Total;

    return View(Data.Data.ToPagedList(page.GetValueOrDefault(),PageSize, Data.Total));
}
```

I have a textbox and pass the value of it into my `Index` ActionResult:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Dealer",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" value="" name="txtDealer" placeholder="Search Dealers by Name, City or State" />
    <img src="/assets/images/search.png" class="search-icon">
}
```

Code behind:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string txtDealer,int? page = 1)
{
    string searchDetails = txtDealer;
    int PageSize = 30;
    int skip = PageSize * (page.GetValueOrDefault() - 1);
    var Data = GetDealersDataByName(PageSize, skip, searchDetails);
    Data.PageSize = PageSize;

    TempData["currentPageIndex"] = page.GetValueOrDefault();
    TempData["PageSize"] = PageSize;
    TempData["Total"] = Data.Total;

    return View(Data.Data.ToPagedList(page.GetValueOrDefault(), PageSize, Data.Total));
}
```

Now, here comes the problem, data from the search textbox is fetched from a Web API. But due to page refresh, my page is fully null.

How to persist the data, so on my page is shows the searched dealer's result, in the same page (`Index.cshtml`)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to post request but anyway,
You can add `TempData["searchName"] = txtDealer;` or just don't use your post function, we use post data for sensitive data not for search, you can use only get function and add paramater txtDealer .